# UISegment Control in UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, xcode4.2, uisegmentedcontrol

[image]I have added a segment control to my table view and what my problem/question is I need to display text in tableview cells based on segment selected.

I have followed some tutorials, in that they gave me text in labels based on segment selected. I used `segmentControl.selectedIndexPath` also. So can anyone tell me how can we set that array of objects to my tableview cells based on segment selected?

Correct me if any mistakes in my english.

Please help me.
Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: You update the datasource right?

Comment: u r asking about tableView datasource right?@Bourne

Comment: Yes. You need to update the tableview datasource.

Comment: yes i updated tableview delegate and datasource @Bourne.with out updating even i dint get tableview. am able to get tableview and on that segment control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to divide your data in different arrays depends on your requirement ie Number of segmentControl.

Here if there are three segment controls then create three array an in the table view's delegate methods depending on segment control's selected index change the array to display in table view.

Like if `segmentControl.selectedIndex == 0` then `array1` if `== 1` then `array2` and if `== 2` then `array3`.

In all delegate and datasource methods of table view. And on segment control's selecedIndexChange: method call reload table.

Happy Coding :)

**EDIT 1**

For change data in table view on segmented control's index change you must have one `IBOutlet` for tableView and use that `IBOutlet` to change the data using `[tableView reloadData];` here `tableView` is `IBOutlet` for table view.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: if need any help feel free to ask :)

Comment: hi @Aalok Parikh, i have done all those u mentioned above, in my screenshot that table data is remains same if i choose another segment.. even though i implemented the based on segment selected index.. i need to write a button action that -(IBAction) segmentedControlIndexChanged. am not getting what logic need to write there...please help me.

Comment: in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method put the if-else if-else part and in that part use appropriate array to return data for display in cell :)

Comment: if (segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) 
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [weekVolOppAry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    if (segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) 
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [weekendVolOppAry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    if (segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) 
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [monthVolOppAry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

Comment: and in segmentedControlIndexChanged method just call `[tableView reload];`

Comment: Ok this looks fine and what about segmentedControlIndexChanged method ? :)

Comment: that method not founding tableView what should i do now..?

Comment: -(IBAction) segmentedControlIndexChanged
{
    switch (self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex) 
    {
        case 0:
            [tableView reloadData];
            break;
        case 1:
                 [tableView reloadData];
            break;
        case 2:
            [tableView reloadData];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

Comment: Have you set IBOutlet for your table view? `tableView` is IBOutlet for your table view. And also just put one single line like [tableView reloadData]; that's it. :)

Comment: In .h file put just like this `@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;` and in .m file `@synthesize tableView;` then use it.

Answer (score 1):

Common use for tableview; 
In Controller you have an array which has the objects, lets say _tableObjects
You have implemented in your controller datasource methods

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     UITableViewCell *cell =......
     .................
     cell.labelText.text = [_tableObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].name;
     return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   return _tableObjects.count;
}
```

So if it is like this, you can change _tableObjects array in somewhere in you code.

```
_tableObjects = myOtherArray;
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Sorry @Mert, i dint get this...:(

Comment: This is the basics of table view. If they do not mean something to you, then I strongly recommend to read http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW10

Comment: i mean this is not applicable to my context here @Mert.i know those basics which u sent in the link.

Comment: I can not help you more then that unless you provide some code.

Comment: i just edited my question above, if u understand my context,help me pls...@Mert